# how to share links with my app?

Tags: android, android-intent

how do i open links in my webview shared by other apps?

I have                                                                                                                                    tried this but it doesn't list my app anywhere-

```
TextView uri = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
    //if (Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        String intentUri = (new Intent("com.example.browsableintent.MY_ACTION"))
                .toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME).toString();
        uri.setText(intentUri);

        Log.w("URLHandler", intentUri);
    //} else {
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        if (data == null) {
            uri.setText(" ");
        } else {
            uri.setText(getIntent().getData().toString());
        }
    //}




// Load URL from Browsable intent filter if there is a valid URL pasted
    if (uri.length() > 0)
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    else
        // dont load
```

manifest

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and copy paste the whole activity and the AndroidManifest file ?

Answer (score 0):

To allow other apps to start your activity, you need to add an `<intent-filter>` element in your manifest file for the corresponding `<activity>` element.

```
<intent-filter > ... </intent-filter>
```

intent filter defines the Intents that your activity "listens for" in order to launch.

```
<action android:name="ndroid.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

Action and category are both fields that get set on an Intent before it is "fired off" into the system. The system will then look for any activities that match both the action and category and if it finds one then it will launch that activity, or if it finds multiple it will show the user all of them and let them pick.

When your app is installed on a device, the system identifies your intent filters and adds the information to an internal catalog of intents supported by all installed apps. When an app calls startActivity() or startActivityForResult(), with an implicit intent, the system finds which activity (or activities) can respond to the intent.

Inside your Activity to the following

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the intent that started this activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();

    // Figure out what to do based on the intent type
    if (intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1) {
        // Handle intents with image data ...
    } else if (intent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
        // Handle intents with text ...
    }
}
```

If you want to return a result to the activity that invoked yours, simply call setResult() to specify the result code and result Intent. When your operation is done and the user should return to the original activity, call finish() to close (and destroy) your activity. For example:

```
// Create intent to deliver some kind of result data
Intent result = new Intent("com.example.RESULT_ACTION", Uri.parse("content://result_uri"));
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

To read more on how to implements click [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html#AddIntentFilter)

Comment: I would highly recommend that you read the documentation its pretty straightforward you should be able to interpret at least whats written there if you want to learn more about android.

Comment: I have edit the answer to explain it more thoroughly i hope it helps. @colechole

Comment: Which url are you talking about ?

Comment: if you want to return some result to the app that open your activity you use setResult see i have updated the answer.

Comment: All the data regarding the app that opened your activity is passed here 
 // Get the intent that started this activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();

Comment: Okay i am doing that in a new answer below

Answer (score 0):

> how do i open links in my webview shared by other apps? I want my app to be here in this list
>
> I have tried this but it doesn't list my app anywhere-

```
TextView uri = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.urlField);

// Get the intent that started this activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
String link = intent.getDataString();

uri.seText(link);
```

Comment: Did you log the l ink what are you getting in  the link ?

Comment: Yes put this inside the onCreate after the setContentVIew(R.layout.main)

Comment: Were you able to get the link ?

Comment: i dont know how to check that

Answer (score -1):

Taken from Chromium AndroidManifest.xml : https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/java/AndroidManifest.xml?q=AndroidManife&sq=package:chromium&l=1

```
<!-- Matches the common case of intents with no MIME type.-->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>

<!-- Same filter as above but with MIME types.-->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Then from other apps it's enought to use:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

and Android will list you in Select App dialog.

**Complete example for client app**: 
In AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.j2ko.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.j2ko.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Main Activity:

```
package com.j2ko.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            handleIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(final Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_VIEW) {
            final String url = intent.getDataString();
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @gaurav4sarma I'm not seeing any relation between my answer and others. colechole does the answer below fix your problem?

Comment: sorry, my question is, how do i Actually load this URL/data/link in my webview when it receives it? after following gaurav's manifest part, my app is getting listed in the "open with" apps. however, i want to load that url

Comment: can you just fix my java part? (see the code in question)

Comment: @colechole then when you extract url from intent do the following `webview.loadUrl(url)` .

Comment: I need more info about the crash - post crash log please.

Comment: @colechole I've updated my answer with full app example.